# ulimit first call ok second call fail, why?

Tags: macos, unix, ulimit, osx-snow-leopard

On macosx 10.7, using bash

The first call to ulimit -n succeeds, while the second fails.

```
a:$ ulimit -n 
2560
a:$ ulimit -n 5000
a:$ ulimit -n 
5000
a:$ ulimit -n 6000
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

however if I try in a new shell (or another shell) to ulimit -n 6000, it succeeds:

```
a:$ ulimit -n 
2560
a:$ ulimit -n 6000
a:$ ulimit -n 
6000
```

Why is that?

Comment: Off-topic for SO - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Agreed, or [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Duplicate of [this superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/309106/strange-behaviour-with-ulimit-on-mac-os-x-10-6/).

Answer (score 4):

From the bash man page:

> A hard limit cannot be increased once it is set; a soft limit may be
>   increased  up to the value of the hard limit. If neither -H nor -S is
>   specified, both the  soft and hard limits are set.

Most modern *NIX's don't actually use `ulimit` anymore.  I'd guess that OS X has no ulimit hard max set, so your first call sets the soft and hard max, and so your second call fails every time.  The first call without a [limit] parameter is probably printing the soft max.